# Selenium, sending text

Tags: java, html, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I'm new to selenium and was hoping to get some help with this. Imagine that we have two boxes, one in which the user can write a message, and one to which the written message will be sent to.
I'm trying to use selenium and java to to send text and assert it was correctly sent to the input and text area (shown in html below).

```
<div id="req5">
<h2>Test #5</h2>
<input type="text" value="Type here" name="input">
<br>
<textarea cols="50" rows="10" name="textarea">Write something  here</textarea>
</div>
```

How would I go about this in Java? Thanks!

Comment: possible duplicate of [Send text and assert, selenium](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28569826/send-text-and-assert-selenium)

Answer (score 0):

```
String yourText = "Lorem hipstum";
WebElement we = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//input")).click();
we.sendKeys(yourText);

Assert.assertTrue("result text compared!", driver.findElement(By.name("textarea")).getTextt().equals(yourText));
```

not quite sure whether the syntax is 100% correct, but this should be the way to go. best regards paul